# Synchronous use of DownloadStringTaskAsync on UI thread

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-8, webclient

This is one of these things where I thought that I knew exactly what is happening, but have been unable to figure how to fix it on Windows Phone 8.  I want to have two methods that read via http; one sync and one async. The sync function is currently being called from the UI thread, but ultimately will probably not be.
The relevant code looks like this:

```
private static string result;

public static string load() {
    Task task = loadAsync();
    task.Wait;
    return result;
}

public async static Task < string > loadAsync() {
        ...
    result = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
}
```

I intended that when I call Task.Wait() the UI thread will wait until the read completes; that's ok - I want the UI to pause until the read completes. But as written I appear to be creating a deadlock, so that everything hangs and the Download never completes, and presumably never starts.  It makes sense that the task.wait() is causing the deadlock, so I created the following Test class:

```
public static class Test
{
    const string apiUrl = @"http://169.254.21.12:51428/api/Q";
    private static WebClient webClient;
    private static Uri uri;
    private static string result;

    public static string Load()
    {
        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
        uri = new Uri(apiUrl);
        try
        {
            Task<string> task = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
            result = task.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { result = null; }
        return result;
    }
```

This class is running in the WP8 Emulator from VS13, talking to a local IIS, also launched as a separate Project in the same Solution. We get to the 'result =' line, but that line never returns. I know that IIS is running and the network link is working, since I can use IE in the phone to reach the URI.

Comment: Are you *trying* to block the UI thread? That's a really bad idea. It doesn't help that you've shown code which won't even compile...

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm sorry - the way I wrote the question was unclear. I've edited to fix hopefully.  I could post the rest of the code, but it's just the setup for the WebClient, so there didn't seem any point. But will do if helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing a [deadlock issue that I describe in detail on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

> I want to have two methods that read via http; one sync and one async.

That's your problem right there. Downloading an HTTP resource is a naturally asynchronous operation, so it should only have an asynchronous API.

Comment: The blog post is dispositive; thank you.  The advice 'async all the way down' is a new mantra.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're currently creating a deadlock.

You're using async/await, which means that when the task returned by `DownloadStringTaskAsync` completes, a continuation will be scheduled to continue `loadAsync` from where it left off, and back in the UI thread.

However, that continuation is never going to actually run because the UI thread is busy waiting for a task to complete... and that task is only going to complete after continuation has run. Deadlock.

Just to block the UI thread, you don't need to use `async`/`await` at all:

```
// Method name changed to follow .NET conventions.
public static string Load() {
    WebClient webClient = ...;
    Task<string> task = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    return task.Result; // Result blocks, just like Wait().
}
```

Comment: That's one of the things that I'd tried, but it still hangs, so there may be something more interesting going on. I've modified the question to include the new stripped down code and what happens with that.

Comment: @jbhelicon: It may be that `DownloadStringTaskAsync` itself schedules some operations on the UI thread. Basically when you start doing something you're not supposed to (blocking the UI thread in this case), anything which assumes you're "behaving properly" may start to fail.

Comment: Fair enough, though you'd think that that would be a strange thing for it to do. But I see that WebClient will want to raise the DownloadFileCompleted event on the UI thread, so that may be it!  Is there a simple way to test that conjecture? Ie spin up and invoke Test using a new thread, and resume the calling thread when done?

Comment: @jbhelicon: Well you could use `Task.Wait(TimeSpan)` to wait just for a short period, and see whether that unblocked it...